# How can I select a value dinamically in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I want to select a value in a select tag using scriptlet  but it doesn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<%int number=2;%>
<br><br>Matricula: 

<select id="mat" name="mat" >

<option<%if(number==1){%>selected<%}%> >
01</option>
<option<%if(number==2){%>selected<%}%> >
02</option>
<option<%if(number==3){%>selected<%}%> >
03</option>
<option<%if(number==4){%>selected<%}%> >
04</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add space between `option` and `selected`

```
<%int number=2;%>
<br><br>Matricula: 

<select id="mat" name="mat" >

<option <%if(number==1){%>selected<%}%> >
01</option>
<option <%if(number==2){%>selected<%}%> >
02</option>
<option <%if(number==3){%>selected<%}%> >
03</option>
<option <%if(number==4){%>selected<%}%> >
04</option>

</select>
```